# Wrong API response?

Tags: bug, status-completed, api

Well, if you look [here](http://api.stackoverflow.com/1.1/users/?filter=genesis&max=10000&min=5000), you'll see i have

```
      "down_vote_count": 94,
```

But if you look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/users/764846/genesis) on my Stackoverflow profile, you see that my down vote count is `64`.

For those who would ask if I'm sure it's not network-wide API, no it's not.

Is it bug?

Comment: The profile pic doesn't show votes on deleted questions

Comment: and why api does?